# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'BuySell_20190423.Controllers.StockController'

Tags: asp.net-core

I have made many additions to this backend. Now the basic HTTPPOST from values controller copied to the stocks controller gives me this error in the chome window:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 
system.String' while attempting to activate 
BuySell_20190423.Controllers.StockController'.
```

This is my stock controller post:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {

    }
```

In postman I get the 500 internal error using this body,

```
{"UserName":"johndoe"}
```

Here is some of my startup.cs

```
namespace BuySell_20190423
{
public class Startup
{


    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", corsBuilder =>
    {
       corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                  .AllowCredentials();
    }));

    services.AddDbContext<Helpers.DataContext>(x => x.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb"));
    services.AddDbContext<Models.StockContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("item"));

    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(x => x.UseInMemoryDatabase("AppDb"));
    // Auto Mapper Configurations
    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
      mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
    });

    IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);
    //services.AddScoped<Post>(_ => new MyService("value here"));
        // configure strongly typed settings objects
        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);


    // configure DI for application services
    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
        // configure DI for string services
        services.AddHttpClient();


        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Here is the stocks controller constructor:

```
        public StockController(String context, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        _context = context;
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like your controller's constructor is requiring a string, which the default DI container cannot give to it.

Comment: @juunas I appreciate your time in responding. I am writing my first app using angular and netcore 2.1.  I added the constructor to the question. Does it look legit?

Comment: You have to remove the `string context` parameter, the dependency injection system can't know what that should be :/

Comment: Or was that supposed to be `StockContext context`?

Comment: That was it. I removed the string context parameter.  I had copied it from a great video on Lynda.com  Thanks for you answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `string context` parameter, the dependency injection system can't know what that should be.